# Не могу корректно запушить свой проект на github

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

Я создала учетную запись на github, и сделала свой первый репозиторий. С помощью команд которые были указаны на сайте после создания репозитория закинула свой проект на git. Но вот в чем проблема, до меня на моем компьютере работал другой разработчик, который тоже использовал git. И не смотря на то, что я сменила аккаунт и имя пользователя глобально, не смотря на то, что ввожу свое имя и пароль при pushe на git, он пушит в мой репозиторий, в мою учетную запись, но от другого программиста, под его именем. Никак не могу это изменить. `git config --list` показывает мое имя. Уже не знаю, что делать. Может кто-то сталкивался?
[image: Имя мое, я зарегистрирована по нику NIKI2224, а пушится от имени gunniball]

Имя мое, я зарегистрирована по нику NIKI2224, а пушится от имени gunniball

Comment: Когда локально делаете `git log`, то показывает правильное имя?

Comment: У меня винда только на работе, потому не могу точно вспомнить последовательность, потому [вот это](https://clck.ru/UXt7E) советую проверить. Может там беда. В менеджере учетных данных в винде.

Comment: Да git log показывает правильное имя и правильную почту.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло, сделала так как указано в ссылке, потом перезагрузила комп и все заработало!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может почта другая указана?
Посмотрите внимательно

```
$ git config --list --show-origin
```

И если почта будет не ваша то

```
$ git config --global user.email "mail@mail.com"
```

Comment: Все проверяла перед тем как писать на stack overflow, и имя мое и почта моя. А постит от его имени(